# Rust diesel the trait bound is not satisfied

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to write basic filter query in Rust Diesel, the `main.rs` filter doesn't work and I don't know what's wrong with it:

```rust
use std::io::Write;
use BriefURL::establish_connection;
use BriefURL::insert_brief_url;
use BriefURL::schema::BriefUrl::dsl::BriefUrl;
use BriefURL::models::BriefUrlModel;
use diesel::prelude::*;
#[cfg(test)]
use diesel::debug_query;
fn main() {
    let connection = &mut establish_connection();
    let user_name = "Anish";
    let url = "https://8gwifi.org";
    let short_url = "tessbrown";
    let long_url = "tessbrown";

    if let Err(e) = insert_brief_url(connection, &user_name, &url, &short_url, &long_url) {
        writeln!(&mut std::io::stderr(), "Error: {}", e).unwrap();
        std::process::exit(1);
    }

    let _results = BriefUrl
        .filter(user_name.eq("Anish"))
        .limit(5)
        .load::<BriefUrlModel>(connection)
        .expect("Error loading posts");
}
```

The `schema.rs`

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
diesel::table! {
    BriefUrl (id) {
        id -> Nullable<Integer>,
        user_name -> Text,
        url -> Text,
        short_url -> Nullable<Text>,
        long_url -> Nullable<Text>,
        clicks -> Integer,
        click_date -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        active -> Integer,
        date_accessed -> Nullable<Timestamp>,
        date_created -> Timestamp,
    }
}
```

The models.rs

```
use diesel::prelude::*;

#[derive(Queryable, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct BriefUrlModel {
    pub id: i32,
    pub user_name: String,
    pub url: String,
    pub short_url: Option<String>,
    pub long_url: Option<String>,
    pub active: i32,
    pub clicks: i32,
    pub click_date: Option<String>,
    pub date_accessed: Option<String>,
}
```

While running the program it throws error

```
the trait bound `bool: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied

   .load::<BriefUrlModel>(connection)
     |          ----                  ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<BriefUrlModel, Sqlite>` is not implemented for `(Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Integer, Nullable<Timestamp>, diesel::sql_types::Integer, Nullable<Timestamp>, Timestamp)`
     |          |
```

**Full stack trace**

```
❯ cargo build
warning: unused import: `diesel::prelude::*`
 --> src/schema.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use diesel::prelude::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: unused import: `models::BriefUrlModel`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:5
   |
12 | use models::BriefUrlModel;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: crate `BriefURL` should have a snake case name
  |
  = help: convert the identifier to snake case: `brief_url`
  = note: `#[warn(non_snake_case)]` on by default

warning: module `BriefUrl` should have a snake case name
 --> src/schema.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     BriefUrl (id) {
  |     ^^^^^^^^ help: convert the identifier to snake case: `brief_url`

warning: `BriefURL` (lib) generated 4 warnings
   Compiling BriefURL v0.1.0 (/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:22:17
    |
22  |         .filter(user_name.eq("ANISH"))
    |          ------ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `bool`
    |          |
    |          required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `diesel::Expression`:
              &'a T
              (T0, T1)
              (T0, T1, T2)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
              (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7)
            and 88 others
    = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>>` to implement `FilterDsl<bool>`
    = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
    = note: required for `table` to implement `FilterDsl<bool>`
note: required by a bound in `diesel::QueryDsl::filter`
   --> /Users/anish/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.3/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:619:15
    |
619 |         Self: methods::FilterDsl<Predicate>,
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::QueryDsl::filter`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: ValidGrouping<()>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:22:10
   |
22 |         .filter(user_name.eq("ANISH"))
   |          ^^^^^^ the trait `ValidGrouping<()>` is not implemented for `bool`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `ValidGrouping<GroupByClause>`:
             <&'a T as ValidGrouping<GB>>
             <(T0, T1) as ValidGrouping<__GroupByClause>>
             <(T0, T1, T2) as ValidGrouping<__GroupByClause>>
             <(T0, T1, T2, T3) as ValidGrouping<__GroupByClause>>
             <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4) as ValidGrouping<__GroupByClause>>
             <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) as ValidGrouping<__GroupByClause>>
             <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) as ValidGrouping<__GroupByClause>>
             <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7) as ValidGrouping<__GroupByClause>>
           and 100 others
   = note: required for `bool` to implement `NonAggregate`
   = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>>` to implement `FilterDsl<bool>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Integer, Nullable<Timestamp>, diesel::sql_types::Integer, Nullable<Timestamp>, Timestamp): load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<BriefUrlModel, Sqlite>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:24:32
     |
24   |         .load::<BriefUrlModel>(connection)
     |          ----                  ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<BriefUrlModel, Sqlite>` is not implemented for `(Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Integer, Nullable<Timestamp>, diesel::sql_types::Integer, Nullable<Timestamp>, Timestamp)`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<U, DB>`:
               (ST0, ST1)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8)
             and 24 others
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, BriefUrlModel>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /Users/anish/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.3/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     |
1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: AppearsOnTable<table>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:24:32
     |
24   |         .load::<BriefUrlModel>(connection)
     |          ----                  ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `AppearsOnTable<table>` is not implemented for `bool`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `AppearsOnTable<QS>`:
               <&'a T as AppearsOnTable<QS>>
               <(T0, T1) as AppearsOnTable<QS>>
               <(T0, T1, T2) as AppearsOnTable<QS>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3) as AppearsOnTable<QS>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4) as AppearsOnTable<QS>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) as AppearsOnTable<QS>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) as AppearsOnTable<QS>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7) as AppearsOnTable<QS>>
             and 88 others
     = note: required for `diesel::query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<bool>` to implement `diesel::query_builder::where_clause::ValidWhereClause<FromClause<table>>`
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `Query`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, BriefUrlModel>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /Users/anish/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.3/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     |
1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: QueryId` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:24:32
     |
24   |         .load::<BriefUrlModel>(connection)
     |          ----                  ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `QueryId` is not implemented for `bool`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `QueryId`:
               &'a T
               ()
               (T0, T1)
               (T0, T1, T2)
               (T0, T1, T2, T3)
               (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
               (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
               (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
             and 180 others
     = note: required for `diesel::query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<bool>` to implement `QueryId`
     = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `QueryId`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, BriefUrlModel>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /Users/anish/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.3/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     |
1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: QueryFragment<Sqlite>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:24:32
     |
24   |         .load::<BriefUrlModel>(connection)
     |          ----                  ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `QueryFragment<Sqlite>` is not implemented for `bool`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `QueryFragment<DB, SP>`:
               <&'a T as QueryFragment<DB>>
               <() as QueryFragment<DB>>
               <(T0, T1) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
               <(T0, T1, T2) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
               <(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) as QueryFragment<__DB>>
             and 217 others
     = note: required for `diesel::query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<bool>` to implement `QueryFragment<Sqlite>`
     = note: 5 redundant requirements hidden
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `QueryFragment<Sqlite>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, BriefUrlModel>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /Users/anish/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.3/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     |
1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<Sqlite as SqlDialect>::SelectStatementSyntax == diesel::query_builder::private::NotSpecialized`
    --> src/main.rs:24:32
     |
24   |         .load::<BriefUrlModel>(connection)
     |          ----                  ^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `diesel::query_builder::private::NotSpecialized`, found struct `backend::sql_dialect::select_statement_syntax::AnsiSqlSelectStatement`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `QueryFragment<Sqlite>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<table>, ..., ..., ..., ..., ...>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, BriefUrlModel>`
     = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/BriefURL/target/debug/deps/BriefURL-88f99135e88d0a5a.long-type-5193104054952781216.txt'
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /Users/anish/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.3/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1499:15
     |
1499 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0271, E0277.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
error: could not compile `BriefURL` due to 7 previous errors
```

Comment: Your schema says `id` is nullable but your struct says `id` is non-optional. Which is it? Change the other. And `Timestamp` [isn't compatible](https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/sql_types/struct.Timestamp.html) with `String` for `click_date` and `date_accessed`. And I think the field order should match.

Answer (score 1):

the model needs to map with the schema.

```
#[derive(Queryable, PartialEq, Debug)]
#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::BriefUrl)]
pub struct BriefUrlModel {
    pub id: i32,
    ....
}
```

I faced a similar case, i guess you just need to select which field you want to return.

````
let _results = BriefUrl
        .filter(user_name.eq("Anish"))
        .limit(5)
        .select(BriefUrlModel::as_select())
        .load::<BriefUrlModel>(connection)
        .expect("Error loading posts");```
````